# creating and naming multiple lists with a for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list that contists of several elements:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

I need a for-loop, that generates multiple lists, that contain all of the elements exept for one element and also want to name them appropriately. It should look something like this:

```
for i in list:
    globals()['list_' + str(i)] = list.remove(i)
```

The result should look like this:

```
list_a = ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
list_b = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
list_c = ["a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 
list_d = ["a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g"]
ect...
```

Comment: Do. Not. Do. This. Use a dictionary.

Comment: **Do not do this**. Use *a container*, like another `list`, or porbably a `dict` here. Don't dynamically modify variables.

Comment: Note, `list.remove(i)` *returns `None`*, why did you expect something else? You'll have to build a new list. Note, you should never modify a list while you iterate over it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
dic = {}
for item in lst:
    dic['list_' + item] = [x for x in lst if not x == item]
print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'list_a': ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'list_b': ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'list_c': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'list_d': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'list_e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'], 'list_f': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g'], 'list_g': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']}
```

Comment: Don't use the name `dict` - it will override a builtin.